# MongoDB $pull from array with filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have User collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: '5b3935c2d4850aa2d9f0ae25',
    feedBucket: [
      {
        _id: '2a3535c2d4852ba2d9f0ae52',
        createdAt: '2018-06-30 21:52:22.681'
      },
      {
        _id: '9f342c2d4852ba2d9f0ae52',
        createdAt: '2018-06-30 21:52:22.681'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: '3d2343c2d4850aa2d9f0ae33',
    feedBucket: [
      {
        _id: '2a3535c2d4852ba2d9f0ae52',
        createdAt: '2018-02-30 21:52:22.681'
      },
      {
        _id: '9f342c2d4852ba2d9f0ae52',
        createdAt: '2018-06-30 21:52:22.681'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I am trying to pull document with id - '9f342c2d4852ba2d9f0ae52' from users feedBucket.

```
await User.updateMany(
  {},
  { $pull: { feedBucket: { _id: '9f342c2d4852ba2d9f0ae52' } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

but it doesn't work, result is { n: 2, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }

Comment: Is this `feedBucket._id` a string or an `ObjectId`? If it's an `ObjectID`, then you'll have to change your modifier.

Comment: Yes it is an `ObjectId`, what do you mean 'then you'll have to change your modifier.'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `feedBucket._id` is ObjectId then you need to `$pull` it by converting to mongoose ObjectId

```
  const user = await User.update(
    { },
    { $pull: { feedBucket: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5b07fa836569d356ba5bd2fa') } } },
    { multi: true }
  )
```